# Javascript file's parent folder

Tags: javascript, string, file, path, substring

every time I need to get the name of a folder a file `targetFile` is located in, I always have to write out this tedious:

`var parentFolder =  targetFile.path.toString().substring(targetFile.path.toString().lastIndexOf('/'), targetFile.path.toString().length)`

am I missing something horribly easy to get this?

Comment: Use another variable... `var path = targetFile.path.toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something that you need to do dynamically? Why not just store it as a constant?

Alternatively, just create a function that executes the code you pasted...

Comment: I will now, I was just curious if something like file.parent existed